# PHPMailer: The following From address failed

Tags: php, email, smtp, sendmail, phpmailer

I have some troubles with my sending loop with PHP Mailer:

```
<?php
foreach ($packTabCible as $key => $pack) {

    // PHPMailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->Mailer        = "smtp";
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
    $mail->SMTPAuth      = true;
    $mail->Encoding      = '8bit';
    $mail->SMTPDebug     = 3;
    $mail->setLanguage('fr', './PHPMailer/language/');
    $mail->CharSet       = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->WordWrap      = 10000;
    $mail->Host          = $hostname;
    $mail->Username      = $username;
    $mail->Password      = $pass;
    $mail->SMTPSecure    = $tls;
    $mail->Port          = $port;

    $mail->FromName = utf8_decode($from_name);
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject  = utf8_decode($sujet);
    $mail->From = $from_mail;

    foreach ($pack as $email => $md5) {         
        $mail->addAddress($email);

        $header  = str_replace("#miroir#", $link_miroir, $ip_header_html);
        $footer  = str_replace("#lien#", $link_unsub, $ip_footer_html);

        $content = str_replace("<body>", "<body>".$header, $message);
        $content = str_replace("</body>", $footer.'</body>', $content);
        $content = str_replace("#email#", $email, $content);

        $mail->Body     = $content;
        $mail->AltBody  = str_replace("#miroir#", $link_miroir, utf8_decode($ip_header_txt))
                        . $txt
                        . str_replace("#lien#", $link_unsub, $ip_footer_txt);

        $mail->send();

        $mail->clearAddresses();

        usleep($timer);
    }

    $mail->SmtpClose();

    usleep(5000000);
}
?>
```

I'm 100% sure of the validity of the parameters I send to PHPMailer.

There is 2 loops, and I reset the connexion after each loop of $packTabCible with $mail->SmtpClose();

But, PHPMailer return the error:

```
The following From address failed: news@my-domain.com : MAIL FROM command failed,0 ok
,
2,SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: 0 ok
 SMTP code: 
2SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: 0 ok
 SMTP code: 
2
```

But news@my-domain.com is the good one so the problem is elsewhere...

If someone have an idea, big thanks

Comment: There's a lot wrong in here. I suggest you look at [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) for how to do this correctly.

Comment: `$mail->SMTPDebug     = 2;`  for error reporting.